# Mongo Array of ObjectID without creating _id field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using $addToSet to add ObjectIDs into an Array, but, since Mongo adds a unique _id field to every ObjectID I add to the Array in question, $addToSet inserts regardless of if the Array already contains ObjectID. The field in question:

```
likes: [ { user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' } } ],
```

How I am using $addToSet:

```
{ $addToSet: { likes: {user: req.session.auth_user._id}}}
```

Sample client side data containing the unpopulated field:

```
0:
user: "5f406e9bae244a383cc9d406"
_id: "5f458f20f4a489683577a21b"
__proto__: Object
1:
user: "5f406e9aae244a383cc9d405"
_id: "5f458f3bf4a489683577a21d"
__proto__: Object
2:
user: "5f406e95ae244a383cc9d403"
_id: "5f45a1c3e8ee4d697715d655"
__proto__: Object
3:
user: "5f406e9aae244a383cc9d404"
_id: "5f46ac03625768751ba31c7b"
__proto__: Object
```

I need to know how to insert ObjectIDs into an Array without generating a unique _id.

Comment: you can try with _id:false
```likes: [ { _id: false, user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' } } ]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1854129/ayush-nawani answered the question in his comment. Setting the field's _id option to false prevents Mongo from adding _ids to the field in question:

```
likes: [ { _id: false, user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' } } ]
```